# Testing movie in Flash CS6?

Tags: flash, testing, export, flash-cs6

I am using Flash CS6 and when I am testing my movie, it exports like this -[image]

Then the movie pops up like this[image]
This is all expected behaviour. But I want to open multiple movies like these at the same time. Can I open multiple instances of the same movie or swf. Note that I do not want to publish to swf and open multiple swfs, because of sandbox security violation warnings. I want to test within the flash cs6.

The reason I want to do this is because I am implementing multiplayer functionality in my game using smartfox server and would like to test two different players playing.

I know I can use localhost to prevent secuirty sandbox violations, but is it just possible to do it within Flash? can i open multiple instances of the test movie at the same time?

Thanks

Comment: IMHO, no way to do that

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `localhost` to your trusted locations here:
http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html

Then you should be able to test your SWFs.